# React native localizations: Global variable

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I am new to React, and I come from the world of `iOS/Android` where localized strings are all defined in dedicated files. I have looked into `react-native-localization` and it seems like we need to define the strings object in each class and then use the values in the rendering. This seems to be quite inefficient and fragmented to me, or maybe I have misunderstood the usage. I haven't been able to find good examples of the usage of `react-native-localization`. I'd really appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 12):

We have used react-native-localization on our project and its very useful this is our usage:

.../ApplicationRoot/utils/strings.js

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

let Strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  ar:{
    hello:'أهلاً',
    howareyou:'كيف حالك؟'
  },
  en:{
    hello:'Hello!',
    howareyou:'How Are You?'
  }

});


module.exports = Strings;
```

after that we import it in any component we want to use it in:

TestComponent.js:

```
import Strings from './utils/strings.js'

...

<Text>Strings.hello</Text>
```

Comment: If I want Telugu Language , Is it Possible To Convert Telugu Language:

Comment: Yes, any language

Comment: Okay ! Thanks for your response. But When I was Choose Language, Okay After App is Close but App is Defaulty Converted to Eng  How Can I Solve this

Comment: how to set specific language

Comment: It is not working on emulators. I changed my language to Arabi and not changed.

Comment: Only Flat Json structure is supported for en and ar? Can't we maintain nested json structure to maintain page level contents? Do we need to maintain only one file per project or we should maintain module level files.? Which is advisable ?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use [this react library](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n)  set up localization. It also has shorthand methods. And it also supports auto language detection of the device.

**UPDATE**

Use this library as the above one is deprecated

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize

Comment: It's compatible with react-navigation? Because as you know when to change the language to Arabia the layout "right to left" will change too ?

Comment: Seems like the above library is deprecated please use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize

Comment: Hmm, to be sure when i change Language the layout will change dynamically ?

Comment: Not sure I haven't tried with any right to left fonts